# Dynamically remove cart fees Woocommerce

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress store using the Woocommerce plugin. I am currently able to add fees dynamically at checkout using the `$woocommerce->cart->add_fee()` function, assigned to the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook. However, I would also like to be able to remove fees at checkout as well, but I haven't managed to make it work. I am attempting to trigger a PHP function via AJAX that will then clear the fees using [this method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart_Fees.html#122-129).

When I simply echo 'success' from the clearfees() function, the AJAX call completes successfully. However, when I try calling $WC()->cart->remove_all_fees() AJAX fails with a 500 error.

Remove fees AJAX call from Javascript

```
function clear_fees() {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: entrada_params.admin_ajax_url,
  data: { action : 'clear_fees' }
  }).done( function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  } )
  .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { // HTTP Error
    console.error( errorThrown );
  } );
}
```

The clearfees function in my theme's functions.php

```
function clearfees() {

  $WC()->cart->remove_all_fees();
  wp_die();

}

// creating Ajax call for WordPress
add_action('wp_ajax_clear_fees', 'clearfees');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_clear_fees', 'clearfees');
```

In my searching I've found very little information on the remove_all_fees() function in practice but it seems like the logical solution if I can get it to work.

Comment: Most of the time, fees are set in a specific hooked function… so you can't remove them this way… It's better to handle a conditional in the hook where the fee is added, which is most of the time `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` … you can use WC_Sessions to set or remove the fee… So in your php ajax function you will set a session value, that will null the fee in `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec But that way it will not be dynamic.

Comment: @needle Shouldn't it be `WC()->cart->remove_all_fees();` instead of `$WC()->cart->remove_all_fees()`?

Comment: If you want to get helped, please add in your question the complete code you are using to set the dynamic fee, explaining the context...

Answer (score 1):

i am doing this as i am apply fees in function.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee_based_on_cart_total', 10, 1 );
function custom_fee_based_on_cart_total( $cart_object ) {
    if(isset($_GET['implementation'])){
        $charges = (int)$_GET['charges'];
        $cart_total = (int)$cart_object->cart_contents_total;
        $fees = $cart_total + $charges;

        $applyfee = $_SESSION['applyfee'] ? $_SESSION['applyfee'] : 'true';
        if($applyfee == 'true'){
            $cart_object->add_fee( __( "Implementation Charges", "woocommerce" ), $charges, false );
        }else{
            $charges = 0;
            $cart_object->add_fee( __( "Implementation Charges", "woocommerce" ), $charges, false );
        }
    }
}
```

and if i select remove fees option

```
function clearfees() {

    $_SESSION['applyfee'] = 'false';
}
// creating Ajax call for WordPress
add_action('wp_ajax_clear_fees', 'clearfees');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_clear_fees', 'clearfees');
```

and at last refresh cart page as i get success responce.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've used these code but remove fee in admin order. 

function clearfees() {

    $_SESSION['applyfee'] = 'false';
}
// creating Ajax call for WordPress
add_action('wp_ajax_clear_fees', 'clearfees');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_clear_fees', 'clearfees');

How can youremove it only in the check cart shopping of client and not in admin?